# Is there a way to set a break point (or points) on every HTTP(S) requests of an iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, http, debugging

I have a relatively large iOS app, which uses various third party modules.
When I run this app and monitor outgoing HTTP(S) traffics using the traffic monitoring app (HTTP Catcher), I see one HTTPS request I am not aware of (and want to eliminate).

I am trying to find out which module is making this request, but I am not able to do so far.

I am wondering if there is a way to set some breakpoints at the system level so that I can catch this request.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You should not be making _any_ http requests. Use https only. If you turn off http at the app level you'll catch the culprit.

Comment: I meant HTTPS precisely speaking. Editing the question and title to clarify.